# How to import normalize, schema function from normalizr node package outside of React in a plain javascript file or simple node project

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, module, normalizr

I must be missing some very basic here about importing an external package function to my plain javascript project / file.

I have a simple project that I have started with **npm init** And then installed the **[normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)** package. I have to run the below kind of normalization code, and this is perfectly working when I run the below code inside a React Component.

**But the import statement itself is failing in my simple plain JavaScript file/project.**

```
const normalize = "./node_modules/normalizr/dist/normalizr.js";
const schema = "./node_modules/normalizr/dist/normalizr.js"; 

const articlesData = {
    articles: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Dagon",
            tags: [{ id: 1, name: "old ones" }, { id: 2, name: "short story" }]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Azathoth",
            tags: [{ id: 1, name: "old ones" }, { id: 3, name: "novel" }]
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "At the Mountains of Madness",
            tags: [{ id: 4, name: "insanity" }, { id: 3, name: "novel" }]
        }
    ]
};

const tag = new schema.Entity("tags", {});
const article = new schema.Entity("articles", {
    tags: [tag]
});

// We assume articlesData is the (parsed) JSON object that we got
const normalizedData = normalize(articlesData, { articles: [article] });

console.log(articlesData);
```

I have also tried to import the 2 functions (normalize, schema) as below which did not work

```
 const normalize = require("normalizr");
 const schema = require("normalizr");
```

And also tried the below way to run the file, which also failed

```
node --experimental-modules ./file.js
```

Had gone through this **[official page](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/introduction.md)** but which was not much help for me.

The below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test-js-codes-repo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash.flatten": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.map": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.omit": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.partialright": "^4.2.1",
    "lodash.pick": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.sortby": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "normalizr": "^3.6.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import it like you would any other module import in Node.js [require docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id)

```
const { normalize, schema } = require('normalizr')
```